When is a multivariate vector function smooth and when is it conformal
This is an exercise from my book. We  re tasked with choosing a  positive, increasing, $C^{\infty}$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ so that $F:S\rightarrow π,[x,y,z]\rightarrow\ [f(z)x,f(z)y,0 ]$ is conformal where $S$ is the cylinder of radius 1 centered around the $z-$axis and $π$ is  the $-xy$ plane. Before that, we must prove $F\in C^{\infty}$.
For the first part, we demand that each of the three  $F_i$, namely,$f(z)x,f(z)y,0\in\ C^{\infty}$. We see that differentiating with respect to $x$ gives (respectively) $f(z),0,0$,with respect to $y$, $0,f(z),0$,and with respect to $z$, $f'(z)x,f'(z)y,0$.
We note that all that the zero results are trivially smooth, $f(z)$ is smooth from the hypothesis and ,$f'(z)x,f'(z)y$ are trivial to prove are smooth by finding the formulas for $k-$th order partial derivatives with respect to $x,y,z$. Due to symmetry, let's take $f'(z)x$ for which $\partial x^k\rightarrow f^k(z),\partial z^k\rightarrow f^k(z)x $ which are obviously smooth for all $k$ and $\partial x^k \partial z^m$ are smooth as well because when $m$ or $k>2$ we reach the zero function which is trivially smooth.
Firstly, I want advice on how can I can make the previous "proof" more rigorous as I know it's not exhaustive and I don't have good enough of an understanding to be sure it's exactly on point either (meaning a sense of whether it's misguided or not)
I'm also having trouble wrapping my head around the second part. Quick look at wikipedia shows a map is conformal if its Jacobian can be written as the product of a positive scalar and a rotation matrix.  But taking one look at the Jacobian in this case, that's not possible. It has a null column which means that any matrix we choose for rotation matrix, it will fail as it won't have $det=1$
Still, if we go through with it, we must demand that \begin{bmatrix}
f(z) & 0 & f'(z)x\\
0 & f(z) & f'(z)y \\0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} has linearly independent rows and columns and unit rows and columns. Setting $||column 1||=1\implies f(z)=1 $ (since f is poitive) and indeed we can then write the Jacobian as the product of a positive scalar (1) and a square matrix that contains within it and a rotation matrix, namely  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
but of course this doesn't stick because $f$ is not increasing (in addition to the resulting matrix not being a rotation matrix).
What am I not getting?

Let $\overline{F}$ be the map $\overline{F}:\mathbb R^3\to π,[x,y,z]\mapsto [f(z)x,f(z)y,0 ]$.
To prove that $\overline{F}$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$, it is sufficient to prove that its coordinate maps are $\mathcal C^\infty$. And this is clear as those maps are the product of $\mathcal C^\infty$ maps.
$F$ that is the restriction of $\overline{F}$ to the smooth submanifold $S$ is therefore $\mathcal C^\infty$.
Regarding the second point, i.e., proving that $F$ is a conformal map, you must notice that $F$ is defined on $S$, not on $\mathbb R^3$. Therefore, you can consider the cylindrical coordinates on $S$ and prove that $F$ is conformal for those coordinates.

Yes, each point on $S$ is desribed by $(sint,cost,z)$ and in that case $F$ gives $f(z)cost,f(z)sint,0$. But isn't this still a problem (even more so) as now there are two variables meaning two partial derivatives meaning 2*3 Jacobian matrix which of course can't be written as a rotation one?

@AnthonyKonstantinou As $F$ last coordinate is always $0$, you may identify $F$ to $F(t, z) = (f(z) \cos t, f(z) \sin t)$.
